# Plotting points on top of .pdf or image files in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to come up with a way of adding points on top of a one page PDF graph in a webpage. The pdf's all have a similar structure, but the x and y axis do not always land in the same spot with respect to pixels to the left/right or top/bottom. The scale is also not always the same. I can make these into images as well if need be. The end goal is to take data from another application and plot it on top of these existing graphs as a background.

I so far have come up with a user unfriendly solution of putting the graph in a canvas, clicking on the x and y axis and setting the x and y position of the graph, and plotting from there.

I was wondering if you had any suggestions on ways to do this in a more automatic fashion. The reason I dont want to generate new line charts in the webpage is because I am running from a database of thousands of these PDF files and they are very complex. Re-making them from scratch just to put in the webpage would take months.

Comment: You could re-make the pdf files on demand, e.g. when a user tries to view or download it. Also, consider posting some code in order to help others to better understand your question, at the moment is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i'm more asking for ways to go about it. They are already generated, in a database. I want to compare test data to the graph and plot that data on top of the graph if that makes more sense